# apply tables properties to asp.net GridView with fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview, css-tables

How to apply this https://codepen.io/daveoncode/pen/LNomBE table CSS to my Gridview, because I need the same grid like on this link. When I copy this CSS and add class names it doesn't work properly, I only get scroll but miss fixed header and footer. How to get whole  with  and set CSS to it inside GridView, and how to do it for footer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            width: 90%;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background: #efefef;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 7px;
        }

        .containerGrid {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 400px;
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
        }

        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td + td {
            border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        }

        td, th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            background: #ff6a00;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        input[type="text"] {
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .thead tr th,
        .tfoot tr td {
            height: 0;
            line-height: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            border: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        tbody tr th {
            background-color: snow;
        }

        .thead tr th,
        .tfoot td {
            position: absolute;
            color: #000000;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-left: -10px;
            line-height: normal;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
            text-align: left;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="containerGrid">
                <asp:GridView ID="Gridview2" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="thead" />
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="tfoot" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ministry">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Ministry" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ministry")%>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMinistry" runat="server" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Criteria">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Criteria" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Criteria")%>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = new { Ministry = "Ministry 0", Title = "Title 0", Criteria = "Criteria 0" };
            var objList = (new[] { obj }).ToList();
            for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
            {
                objList.Add(new { Ministry = "Ministry " + i.ToString(), Title = "Title " + i.ToString(), Criteria = "Criteria " + i.ToString() });
            }
            Gridview2.DataSource = objList;
            Gridview2.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding the code below. By default a GridView does not generate `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements. So your CSS will not work properly.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview2" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">

protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this does what did you say but still CSS doesn't apply the same as on the link, do you have another solution or example of how to fix header and footer and add scroll on gridview?